# Selectbox Options List dynamic width

Tags: javascript, css

I have a Datagrid Layout with 5 Columns.
Each column head Contains a Selectedbox, as a Sort options.

And Each Column has a fixed width of 160px.
Now my Problem is, If option Text is too Long e.g "Doppelzimmer/Bad/WC/Balkon oder Terrasse"
in FF the options list will expanded, but in IE, the text will be Cut after 160px in Options list.

Is there a way to Fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of the select element using CSS:

```
<select style="width:160px">
```

Comment: I need a dynamic width, depending on the length of its contents.

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous.  What are you trying to do?  You're saying it works in Firefox one way, and IE another, then saying "how do I fix it?"   Which way do you want it to work?  I've given instructions to make it work the same (like Firefox) everywhere.  If, instead, you don't want the text to be truncated ever, (but want a minimum width of 160px when it's less than that), then do this:  Instead of "width" on the select, set it to "min-width".  Next, remove your width setting on your columns.